# Python Code Error with Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

When I try to run the code it gives me this nasty error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1475, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "E:\Tkinter\count_num_CHALLENGE.py", line 39, in count_num
    for num in range(start, end):
TypeError: 'Entry' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Please help I don't know what is wrong! I tried int() Around entry but that did not work either If you guys can help me out that would  be great. As I am in need of assistance

```
from tkinter import *

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super(Application, self).__init__(master)
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        # Create the instruction Label
        Label(self,
              text = "Enter a starting number then an ending number."
              ).grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = W)

        # Create the entry box for starting/ending
        self.starting_num = Entry(self)
        self.starting_num.grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = W)

        self.ending_num = Entry(self)
        self.ending_num.grid(row = 3, column = 0, sticky = W)

        # Create the text box
        self.result_txt = Text(self, width = 20, height = 10, wrap = WORD)
        self.result_txt.grid(row = 4, column = 0, columnspan = 1)

        # Submit button
        Button(self,
               text = "Count the numbers",
               command = self.count_num
               ).grid(row = 5, column = 0, sticky = W)

    def count_num(self):
        start = self.starting_num
        end = self.ending_num

        for num in range(start, end):
            print(num)

        self.result_txt.delete(0.0, END)
        self.result_txt.insert(0.0, count_num)    

# Main
root = Tk()
root.title("Count the numbers")
app = Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `self.starting_num` is an instance of an Entry widget, but you are trying to use it as if it were a number just as the error message is telling you.

I'm going to guess your intent is to use the value of the entry widget, in which case you need to use something like `start=int(self.starting_num.get())`, though you will need to handle the case where the entry is emply or has non-digits in it. The same goes for `ending_num`